# confused about the annotation on pdb website

Tags: bioinformatics, pdb, protein-database

I don't understand the C [auth B] meaning in the Chain columns. Also, i am wondering why the name of molecule is so long in the second figure. Thanks for advance
[image]

[image]

Comment: The PDB can rename chains after deposition. `auth` here stands for author. `B [auth C]` likely means that originally it was named (by author) C and then renamed by the PDB to C.
Note: this is not a programming question. Perhaps it'd be on-topic on biology.SE or bioinformatics.SE.